# How to reference csproj from kproj

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I was playing around with `VS2015` and `ASP.NET vNext`, and got stuck on trying to add a reference from vNext class library (kproj) to a regular class library (csproj) in the same solution. Visual Studio 2015 shows the following error message:

> "The following projects are not supported as references".

Is it possible at all to add references to csproj from vNext class libraries?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note: The kpm command has been replaced by dnu.

Visual Studio 2015 Preview (as of writing this) comes with the ASP.NET 5 stable release beta1. In this version there is no way to reference a csproj project from an ASP.NET 5 project.

However, on the development feed of ASP.NET 5 the command `kpm wrap` was introduced to support referencing csproj-projects from ASP.NET 5 projects. See the github [issue #827](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/827) in the aspnet/KRuntime repository and [pull request #875](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/pull/875) which closes the issue.

Here is an example how you would use `kpm wrap`:

Make sure the newest version of the [KRuntime is installed](https://github.com/aspnet/Home#install-the-k-version-manager-kvm) (check this with the `kvm list` command) (I tested this with version `1.0.0-beta2-10709`).

Create an ASP.NET 5 class library project, I used the name ClassLibrary1.

Create a "normal" csproj class library, I named this ClassLibrary2 (make sure you put this in the src folder).

From the commandline, from the **solutiondirectory** run the command

`kpm wrap .\src\ClassLibrary2`

This gives the output:

```
Wrapping project 'ClassLibrary2' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
 Source C:\Users\andersns\Source\ClassLibrary1\src\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj
   Target C:\Users\andersns\Source\ClassLibrary1\wrap\ClassLibrary2\project.json
   Adding bin paths for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
     Assembly: ../../src/ClassLibrary2/obj/debug/ClassLibrary2.dll
     Pdb: ../../src/ClassLibrary2/obj/debug/ClassLibrary2.pdb
```

Now in the project.json of ClassLibrary1 (which is ASP.NET 5) you can add a reference to ClassLibrary2 with this:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "ClassLibrary2": ""
},
...
```

Note: `kpm wrap` did not run properly for me with cmd, I needed to launch powershell to make it run.

Comment: Man @AndersNS, you are bleeding edge :). We're still fixing issues with it and also working on integrating this into visual studio Add Reference dialog.

Comment: PS > kpm wrap
System.Exception: TODO: Error: unrecognized argument 'wrap'
Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.HandleUnexpectedArg(CommandLineApplication co
mmand, String[] args, Int32 index, String argTypeName)
Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: How upgrade to 1.0.0-beta2-10709 ?                                 PS > kvm upgrade
Determining latest version
KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1 already installed.
Adding C:\Users\user\.kre\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Users\user\.kre\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin to user PATH
Updating alias 'default' to 'KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1'

Comment: Will the tooling eventually support the reverse scenario to let older class libraries reference ASP.NET 5 libraries if, say, they also target net45 in addition to the aspnet50x frameworks? I know this could be done somewhat more manually, but it would be nice to be able to have everything play together in mixed solutions when possible.

Comment: @Adam not sure how that would work given how the net45 target framework works vs how aspnet5 works. Maybe in the future? Start another question with that maybe, interesting question. :)

Comment: @RouR Reinstall your KVM by running the install script you can find from the dev branch https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev#windows-1. This will make it aware of the nuget feed from the dev-build.

Comment: Why should I put that referenced .csproj under "src" folder? I tried that and the result was not what I did expect: all files under .csproj were then available in referencing .kproj, and nobody wants that.  -- additionally, if I tried to add existing project and pointed to that wrap/ClassLibrary2/project.json, no source files were available, so I couldn't use classes from that library.

Comment: For me, "kpm wrap" seems to create completely empty projects with absolutely no source files. .NET Frameworks are correct, assembly paths seems to be reasonable and all, but I cannot see or use any of those classes that were in .csproj -project through that .kproj wrap. Used kpm version is 1.0.0-beta3-11030, and I'm using powershell

Comment: That is how kpm wrap works currently I believe. Not very smooth or pretty I agree. kpm wrap is the first of many steps towards adding support to reference .csproj files from .kproj files as far as I understand. I'm not sure what the future plans for that functionality is.

Comment: AndersNS: do you know any pointers how to complete all the rest steps to really have a useful reference from .kproj to .cproj? Currently it seems that it's just useless. We can now reference the projects, but as there are no classes available, we can't really use any of those classes that are on .cproj -projects.

Comment: I don't really have that much experience with it. I have just converted csproj's to project.json projects if I need them. :) You can check out this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/8. Maybe it has some hints for you.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with (Visual Studio 2015 RC) the **kpm** command has been replaced by **dnu**

> The dnu command stands for (.NET Development Utility)

```
dnu wrap .\src\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj
```

New ASP.NET Features and Fixes in Visual Studio 2015 RC
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/29/new-asp-net-features-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2015-rc.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I have found it easiest to simply create a corresponding .kproj for the .csproj I want to reference. The .kproj does not require listing every included file, so this is rather straightforward.

You can create YourProject.kproj as a text file with the contents below, and only replace the [REPLACE_WITH_UNIQUE_GUID] and [ROOT_NAMESPACE].

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>[REPLACE_WITH_UNIQUE_GUID]</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>[ROOT_NAMESPACE]</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">..\artifacts\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\artifacts\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <ProduceOutputsOnBuild>True</ProduceOutputsOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

You can then add this project to your solution and reference it from your MVC 6 project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this answer I found out that you need to use the if directive (#if) to make the call without errors:

Something like:

```
#if ASPNET50 
 using class2
#endif
```

When you use it in a call you need to do the same.

```
#if ASPNET50
   ViewBag.Message = class2.Class1.Greetings()
#endif
```

Comment: Update: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537496/vnext-cant-see-namespace-in-referenced-package. If you remove in the project.json the framework ASPNET50CORE you do not need to use that ugly directive :)