# vNext can't see namespace in referenced package

Tags: c#, asp.net, roslyn, asp.net-core

Program.cs

```
using System;
using RazorEngine;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
            string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "RazorEngine": "3.4.2"
  },
  "commands": {
    "run": "run"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `kpm build`, I get this output (included only relevant info)

```
Building RazerEngineTester for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
Using Project dependency RazerEngineTester 1.0.0
Source: /Users/mason/Desktop/Dot Net Solutions/RazerEngineTester/project.json

Using Package dependency RazorEngine 3.4.2
Source: /Users/mason/.kpm/packages/RazorEngine/3.4.2
File: lib/net45/RazorEngine.dll

Building RazerEngineTester for Asp.NetCore,Version=v5.0
Using Project dependency RazerEngineTester 1.0.0
Source: /Users/mason/Desktop/Dot Net Solutions/RazerEngineTester/project.json

Using Package dependency RazorEngine 3.4.2
Source: /Users/mason/.kpm/packages/RazorEngine/3.4.2

Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RazorEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why am I getting this compilation error even though it pulls down the RazorEngine NuGet package correctly, and [according to the source code](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/src/source/RazorEngine.Core/Razor.cs), the `RazorEngine` namespace exists?

Comment: Is RazorEngine.Core listed in your references?  If so, is it underlined with squiggly yellow or red lines?

Comment: @JohnKoerner No. All of my references are listed above. If you look at [source](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/src/source/RazorEngine.Core/Razor.cs), the `Razor` class is not in `RazorEngine.Core` namespace (though it is in that folder). I don't even see a `RazorEngine.Core` namespace in that project.

Comment: RazorEngine.Core is the name of the DLL not the name of the Namespace.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I tried to add `RazoreEngine.Core` as a dependency, and I got `Unable to locate RazorEngine.Core >= 3.4.2`. If `RazorEngine.Core` was a dependency of `RazorEngine`, wouldn't the `kpm restore` automatically pull that in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at closely to Razor.Parse method, it will say following thing.

It is available for asp.net 5.0 but not for core.

[image]

Now if you remove framework from project.json then it will work.

```
   {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "RazorEngine": "3.4.2"
    },
    "commands": { 
        "run" : "run"
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "aspnet50" : { }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I arrived at that conclusion a little ahead of you. However, I don't have the luxury of handy Intellisense to tell me that, as I'm developing on my Mac at the moment. Using the command line and Sublime Text.

Comment: Great. If it works for you. Commandline is great and it reminds me when I have limited RAM still have to compile C# program.I want to explore vnext on MAC but I don't have it :)

Comment: It's nice to use OS X (I'm on a nearly 7 year old MacBook), but it really makes you miss Visual Studio. Hey, we got Office on Mac, iOS, and Android. Maybe next MS will decide to do VS on OS X!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that even though I got that compilation error, if I ran `k run` then it would run properly. So then I realized that the `aspnetcore50` framework was failing to build, but I didn't really care about that one anyways, and that the `aspnet50` framework compiled just fine. So I modified my project.json file to remove that framework and it worked.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "RazorEngine": "3.4.2"
  },
  "commands": {
    "run": "run"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {}
  }
}
```