# vNext: Referencing non-vNext projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Is it possible to reference non-vNext projects (e.g. c# class libraries) from a ASP.NET vNext project?

1. Create empty Visual Studio solution
2. Create standard c# class library
3. Create empty ASP.NET vNext web project

Upon trying to reference the class library, the following error occurs:

```
The following projects are not supported as references "...."
```

---

#### Update

I tried creating custom vNext class library project files for them in the same location (with a related project.json file for dependencies), but I had to notice that many NuGets (for example Ninject) can't be loaded/compiled with that way, so this option obviously doesn't work either.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net45": {           // doesn't work
        "dependencies": {
            "Ninject": "3.2.2.0",
            "Ninject.Extensions.Interception": "3.2.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
 "aspnet50": {        // doesn't work either
        "dependencies": {
            "Ninject": "3.2.2.0",
            "Ninject.Extensions.Interception": "3.2.0.0"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in the Beta 1 or previous releases, but is on the way with the upcoming `wrap` functionality, which allows you to "wrap" traditional class libraries in a `project.json` that the vNext projects can understand.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026946/3912048 for much more info.

As far as Nuget packages go, that will be up to the maintainer as to which of the target frameworks they support. I've not really had any trouble when targeting `net45,` but obviously the results are more mixed with the others for now.